# How big is a world on mobile?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I'm building a Hell Bridge for a fight against the Wall of Flesh, and I was wondering how long the world is! Could someone answer? I mean block-wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Terraria wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Map_size), all maps in Terraria mobile are the same size as small worlds on PC. This is 4200 blocks wide by 1200 blocks tall.